# Copy google sheets data to another workbook with text formula as static text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below that copies data from one google sheets workbook to another however I do have a formula that is copying as a date value however I want it to copy as a text value. It is currently copying as
01/01/2023 11;20:00 (date)
I want it to copy as
01/01/2020 11:20 AM (text)

```
=arrayformula(text(A2:A, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
```

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "ID1";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Overview";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "ID2";
var targetWorksheetName = "Overview Static";
function importData() {
  

  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  //Uncomment line 11 below and comment out line 9 if you want to sync a named range. Replace "teamBugs" with your named range.
  //var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("data");
 
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
  toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "ID1";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Overview";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "ID2";
var targetWorksheetName = "Overview Static";
function importData() {
  

  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  //Uncomment line 11 below and comment out line 9 if you want to sync a named range. Replace "teamBugs" with your named range.
  //var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("data");
  var ts = thisSpreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var replacedData = thisData.getValues().map(row => 
    row.map((v, i) =>
      // Assuming the dates are in the first column
      i === 0 ? Utilities.formatDate(v, ts, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a') : v
    )
  );
 
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
  toRange.setValues(replacedData); 
}
```

Referneces:

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

Comment: Thank you. It gives me some errors though...  
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
(anonymous) @ OverviewCopy.gs:17
(anonymous) @ OverviewCopy.gs:15
importData @ OverviewCopy.gs:14

Comment: These are the rows...  var replacedData = thisData.getValues().map(row => 
    row.map((v, i) =>
      // Assuming the dates are in the first column
      i === 5 ? Utilities.formatDate(v, ts, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a') : v
    )

Comment: It represents that the 'date' in the 6th column is not a `Date` but a `String`. Share a copy of your sheet.